# Insert CSV data in MySQL field table

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a question about CSV data file and MySQL. I get a MySQL Database with maybe 40 tables and I would like filling a field in my llx_societe table from a CSV file.

My table looks like :

```
mysql> select * from llx_societe limit 1 ;
+-------+-----------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
| rowid | nom       | name_alias | entity | ref_ext | ref_int | statut | parent | tms                 | datec | status | code_client | code_fournisseur | code_compta | code_compta_fournisseur | address              | zip   | town        | fk_departement | fk_pays | phone | fax  | url  | email | skype | fk_effectif | fk_typent | fk_forme_juridique | fk_currency | siren | siret | ape  | idprof4 | idprof5 | idprof6 | tva_intra | capital | fk_stcomm | note_private | note_public | model_pdf | prefix_comm | client | fournisseur | supplier_account | fk_prospectlevel | fk_incoterms | location_incoterms | customer_bad | customer_rate | supplier_rate | fk_user_creat | fk_user_modif | remise_client | mode_reglement | cond_reglement | mode_reglement_supplier | cond_reglement_supplier | fk_shipping_method | tva_assuj | localtax1_assuj | localtax1_value | localtax2_assuj | localtax2_value | barcode | fk_barcode_type | price_level | outstanding_limit | default_lang | logo | canvas | import_key | webservices_url | webservices_key | fk_multicurrency | multicurrency_code |
+-------+-----------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|     1 | A.D.P.N.  | NULL       |      1 | NULL    | NULL    |      0 |   NULL | 2016-06-02 10:11:46 | NULL  |      1 | NULL        | NULL             | NULL        | NULL                    | 5  rue des Narcisses | 67116 | REICHSTETT  |              0 |       1 |       | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  |           0 |         8 |                 38 | NULL        | NULL  | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |         0 | NULL         | NULL        | NULL      | NULL        |      1 |           0 | NULL             | NULL             |         NULL | NULL               |            0 |             0 |             0 |          NULL |          NULL |             0 |           NULL |           NULL |                    NULL |                    NULL |               NULL |         0 |               0 |            NULL |               0 |            NULL | NULL    |               0 |        NULL |              NULL | NULL         | NULL | NULL   | NULL       | NULL            | NULL            |             NULL | NULL               |
+-------+-----------+------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------+-------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+--------------+------+--------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And I want to fill the code_client field with a CSV file which looks like :

```
1
20
30
40
60
70
90
17
```

So each line in my llx_societe table corresponding to a CSV file number.

```
rowid 1 : code_client = 1
rowid 2 : code_client = 20
rowid 3 : code_client = 30
...
```

I'm reminding on my paper How I can do that and I'm not sure where I need to specify the field :

```
mysql> use dolibarr ;
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '~/code_client.csv' 
       REPLACE INTO TABLE 'llx_societe'
       CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

But where I have to specify the code_client MySQL column ?

Thank you for helping me and sorry if my English isn't perfect ^^

Comment: do you want to import csv file

Comment: Yes of course .. It's the objective of my post ..

Comment: do you using any gui i.e., user interface for db. If yes, then there will be a option to import of CSV file.

Comment: No I don't use any Database interface. Just the linux terminal.

Comment: ok you can use phpmyadmin as db user interface